# Continue moving files when process stopped

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I was transferring (moving) files from one drive to another. Then the computer was out of battery and it did a shutdown.

Now I see the group of files I wanted to move "50% opacity" in the destination folder. I can do nothing with them. And if I try to move again from the source, it says that the files are in use.

How can I **resume** the move?

Did I lose any files in the source drive? I ask this because some of them moved, and now they are **not** in the source folder... but the destination folder is "untouchable".

Comment: Are there any non-translucent files in the destination folder, and is the number of translucent files in the destination folder identical to the number of solid files in the source folder?

Comment: yes, it was a folder with tons of files, and a separate file ... two items in total. Solid in source, translucent in destination.

Answer (score 1):

If the source has the same number of solid files as the destination has translucent, it is safe to manually resume the move. Drag and drop to move from source to destination, and select "replace" when prompted. Translucent files are just empty placeholder files.

My personal practice always involves copying, then deleting once done. To insist on a copy, hold down <kbd>Option</kbd>. It's a bit more tedious but it's saved me much frustration over this sort of matter.

Comment: Well, if I do that , it does not resume or replace ... it creates a " 2" suffixed file. I guess I have to delete the "translucent" files first if you are sure they are just empty placeholders ;-)